# Rotate PDF in VB.net forms with a button and save it afterwards

Tags: vb.net, pdf, rotation

I am very new to managing PDF's in Vb.net, as for now I can open and view a PDF file in vb form. 
the code goes like this:

```
   OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
 AxAcroPDF1.src = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
```

But now I am stuck on how to rotate the view with a button. lets say I have 3 buttons 1 for clockwise rotation and the other for counterclockwise. And then I have a save button which saves the file to the rotated state. is this even possible?

I am using the adobe PDF reader in COM.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is **no**, not with the provided control. You need a third library to do this. The 3rd party controls work by creating a new image from the page you want to rotate and save that image as a new pdf page. Look into other pdf components to suit your needs. Most are not free, the good ones are pricey.

Here are some....

-iTextSharp

-PDFTron

-DynamicPDF

-PDFSharp

Comment: Thanks for replying, but can you give some example for free third parties out there please?

Comment: See the answer. Its a short list.

Comment: THANKS. I'll look it up.

Comment: I think these libraries do not allow display PDF

Comment: I have used the top two for more than a few years professionally especially PDFTron. Can you describe what you mean by `do not allow display PDF`?

Comment: ITextSharp does not allow to view pdf, pdfSharp - does not allow, PdfTron - it's web-based solution, not a winforms. from the entire list only dinamicPdf can be used. conclusion: provided list is useless

Comment: Do your research first. https://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/index.html thats for PDFTron. iText and PDFSharp support pdf creation and everything above. Who cares if those dont have a viewer, thats not the point of what the user needs.

Comment: Oh I forgot if I didnt mention I work with Pdf creation daily. Hence I work with 2 of them out of the list...